# Problem with discord bot, cogs dont wanna work

Tags: python-3.x, discord, disnake

```
import os
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", help_command=None , intents=disnake.Intents.all())

@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
    await ctx.send("Cogs id loaded...")

@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    bot.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
    await ctx.send("Cogs id inloaded...")

@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def reload(ctx, extension):
    bot.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
    bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
    await ctx.send("Cogs id reloaded...")


for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
        bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")

bot.run("")
```

I’m making a bot for my discord server and I’m using the disnake library, trying to make cogs and the part of the code that is responsible for entering the folder and uploading files is not responding

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you could make a function where you put your code inside and then call the function on startup:

```py
def load_cog():
   for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
        bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    load_cog()
```

I haven't tested this but it should work for you.